# Find Objects[tweets] with specific HashTags in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to get all the Objects[tweets] with the specific Hashtag (JoinPositivePakistan)

Here is the sample of the object in MongoDB

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c3d8522950e2018ccfe94da"),
"created_at" : "Tue Jan 15 07:00:29 +0000 2019",
"id" : NumberLong(1085069192993353729),
"id_str" : "1085069192993353729",
"text" : "RT @wasimbrohi: Pakistan is beautiful country with full of natural colours and colourful cultures.\n#JoinPositivePakistan",
"truncated" : false,
"entities" : {
    "hashtags" : [ 
        {
            "text" : "JoinPositivePakistan",
            "indices" : [ 
                99, 
                120
            ]
        }
    ],
    "symbols" : [],
    "user_mentions" : [ 
        {
            "screen_name" : "wasimbrohi",
            "name" : "Wasim Brohi",
            "id" : 396599753,
            "id_str" : "396599753",
            "indices" : [ 
                3, 
                14
            ]
        }
    ],
    "urls" : []
},
```

I tried the queries as following but not able to get

```
db.getCollection('testdata').find({"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"JoinPositivePakistan"}]}});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to search for

```
{"entities.hashtags.text": "JoinPositivePakistan"}
```

Your query searches for a subdocument in the array that only consists of

```
{"text": "JoinPositivePakistan"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can search Embedded documents directly using below query. No matter how many documents are inside of an array.

```
db.testdata.find({"entities.hashtags.text": "JoinPositivePakistan"})
```

Run It your result is waiting for You...